# VBA: Paste function causes 1004 error after the paste range is cleared

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with my code, when i try copy some piece of data from one sheet ("Import") to another ("TIs"). There is a range in the second sheet, that is cleared before the data is copied. When I try to paste it, I get a

> Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

```
Sub Data()
Sheets("Import").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("TIs").Range("A2:F10000").ClearContents

Dim sPath As String 'Input file path
Dim k As Integer
Dim CopyData

CopyData = 10

For k = 1 To 1 'For now k=1
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\InputData\Data (" & k & ").csv"                           'defines a path to csv file
    copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet sPath, ",", "Import"                                         'imports data from csv file to "Import" Sheet (this is another functions, it works perfectly)
    DataLength = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Import").Range("B:B"))        'defines last row where are imported data
    Sheets("Import").Range(Cells(CopyData + 1, 2), Cells(DataLength, 7)).Copy Sheets("TIs").Range("A2")     'copies it from one sheet to another
Next k

End Sub
```

This worked perfectly, before i run for the first time Clear / ClearContents function. In the first version this range hasn't been cleared and it worked fine. Then i run a macro with Clear function for the first time, and from this time "paste" function doesn't work at all - no matter if Clear / ClearContents function is commented or not.

Do you know what the problem is?
Thank you for support.

Comment: And which sheet is active when you are running this?

Comment: The first one - "Import"

Comment: Always reference the sheet for your `Cells` like `Sheets("Import").Cells` or this could fail. Also `Dim CopyData As Long`. Also `DataLength` should be declared as `Long` • I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. • Can you tell the values of `CopyData` and `DataLength` please?

Comment: Thank you. And by the way - this worked perfectly, before i run for the first time Clear / ClearContents function.

Comment: DataLength in this example is 3713 (but it can reach max ~8000). CopyData is 10 in this example, but it can reach ~3000. The aim is to remove irrelevant data, that usualy are on the first part of csv file.

Comment: Your solution works. Thank you for support.

Answer (score 0):

User PEH solved the problem. The problem was with reference to the sheet with line

```
Sheets("Import").Range(Cells(CopyData + 1, 2), Cells(DataLength, 7)).Copy Sheets("TIs").Range("A2")     'copies it from one sheet to another
```

The correct version is:

```
Sheets("Import").Range(Sheets("Import").Cells(CopyData + 1, 2), Sheets("Import").Cells(DataLength, 7)).Copy Sheets("TIs").Range("A2")     'copies it from one sheet to another
```